# Pass data via segue between 2 view controllers and update labels

Tags: xcode, swift, uilabel, segue, viewcontroller

I am trying to pass `var projectNumber` from ViewController to Project1ViewController via segue and save it as `var projectNum`.  Then use `projectNum` to update the labels in Project1ViewController.  The segue and action/outlets are all set up.  The app runs fluently (no errors), however, `projectNum` in Project1ViewController is not getting the `projectNumber` value and making it `projectNum`.

How do I pass the `projectNumber` value from ViewController to Project1ViewController and save it in `projectNum`? I've seen tutorials that describe similar actions being performed via delegates, but I'm unsure if delegates are applicable to my question. Any feedback helps.

ViewController

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController{

var projectNumber:String = "" 
@IBOutlet var projectButton1 : UIButton!
@IBOutlet var projectButton2 : UIButton!
@IBOutlet var projectButton3 : UIButton!
@IBOutlet var projectButton4 : UIButton!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

@IBAction func updateLabels(sender: UIButton!) {

    projectNumber = String(sender.tag)
    println(projectNumber)
    sender.setTitle(String(projectNumber), forState: UIControlState.Normal)

    func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue!, sender: AnyObject!) {
            //if user presses Project 3921 button
        if segue.identifier == "Project3921Segue"
        {
            if var destinationVC = segue.destinationViewController as? Project1ViewController{
                destinationVC.projectNum = projectNumber
            }
        }
            //if user presses Project 3922 button
        else if segue.identifier == "Project3922Segue"
        {
            if var destinationVC = segue.destinationViewController as? Project1ViewController{
                destinationVC.projectNum = projectNumber
            }
        }
            //if user presses Project 3923 button
        else if segue.identifier == "Project3923Segue"
        {
            if var destinationVC = segue.destinationViewController as? Project1ViewController{
                destinationVC.projectNum = projectNumber
            }
        }
            //otherwise user presses Project 3924 button
        else if segue.identifier == "Project3924Segue"
        {
            if var destinationVC = segue.destinationViewController as? Project1ViewController{
                destinationVC.projectNum = projectNumber
            }
        }   
    }        
}
}
```

Project1ViewController

```
import UIKit

class Project1ViewController: UIViewController {

var projectNum:String!
@IBOutlet var projectNumLabel: UILabel!
@IBOutlet var projectNumTitle: UINavigationItem!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    projectNumLabel.text = projectNum
    projectNumTitle.title = projectNum
    println(projectNum)

    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
}

override func viewWillAppear(animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillAppear(animated)
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}
}
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You are defining `prepareForSegue`*inside* the button action function. It is a `ViewController` function to be overridden.
Your solution can be way more simpler:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController{


    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }


    override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
        if var destinationVC = segue.destinationViewController as? Project1ViewController{
            destinationVC.projectNum = segue.identifier
        }
    }
}
```

Note you do not need the button outlets, since you just configure them in the storyboard with the proper segue identifier. Unless you need some other custom action to be triggered by the buttons.

And:

```
class Project1ViewController: UIViewController {

    var projectNum:String!
    @IBOutlet var projectNumLabel: UILabel!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        projectNumLabel.text = projectNum
        self.title = projectNum
        println(projectNum)

    }
}
```

Note I just set the `title` property of `Project1ViewController` in order to present the `projectNum` as the title in the navigation controller. I assume your controllers are embedded in a navigation controller and the `ViewController`'s buttons has `show` segues to `Project1ViewController`.